# React.js TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I make just simple "todo-list" with Hooks.

This error doesn't reveals where is the problem so i don't know where to fix it.
I searched for hint to solve this error, but i could find a little.

What does this error message mean about my code?

Here is my code.

```
//actions.js
export const addTodo = todo => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  payload: {todo: todo}
})

//reducers.js
export const todoReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return { todoList: [...state.todo, action.payload]};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

//store.js
import * as React from 'react'
import { todoReducer } from "./reducers";

const initialState = {
  todoList: [],
}

export const Store = React.createContext(initialState)

export const StoreProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(todoReducer, initialState)
  return (
    <Store.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>{children}</Store.Provider>
  )
}
```

```
//component.jsx
import React from "react";
import { Store } from "./store";

const TODOLIST = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useContext(Store)
  return(
    <>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'ADD_TODO', payload: state.todo})}>ADD</button>
      <ul>
        {state.todoList.map((tl, index) =>
          <li key={index}>{tl}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}

export default TODOLIST
```

```
//App.jsx
import TODOLIST from './component';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <TODOLIST />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { StoreProvider } from "./store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <StoreProvider>
      <App />
  </StoreProvider>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: *"Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance"* is nothing to do with React specifically, it means you have (or some code you call has) done `[/* ... */] = something` or `[...something]` where you can't do that with `something`.

Comment: You have `[...state.todo` did you mean`[...state.todoList` instead?

Comment: The value of the provider is an object, but you're destructuring an array, that might cause bugs as well: `const [state, dispatch] = React.useContext(Store)`

Answer (score 4):

Correct this

```
export const todoReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return { todoList: [...state.todoList, action.payload.todo]};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

As you are passing todo object to payload

```
export const addTodo = todo => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  payload: {todo: todo}
})
```

Comment: also, `...state.todoList`

Comment: @EmileBergeron yeah, thanks

Comment: thank you guys! i can understand this error meaning a bit more, but this error message doesn't change after i corrected my code as you raised.

Comment: i suggest there is the problem with store or provider that conveys something.  how can i fix this error?
```TODOLIST
src//component.jsx:4
  1 | import React from "react";
  2 | import { Store } from "./store";
  3 | 
> 4 | const TODOLIST = () => {
  5 |   const [state, dispatch] = React.useContext(Store)
  6 |   return(
  7 |     <>
```